# How to git fetch & reset automatically whenever a bash script is executed

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, github

So the thing is the bash script which is to be executed in my device is constantly being updated on github.

So everytime there is an update of bash script on github ....

I have to run - **git fetch origin; git reset --hard @{u}**  everytime manually in terminal to make sure that my local script is **exactly on par** with the script on github. (Yes the bash script is cloned from a git repo )

I was wondering how can i implement these 2 git command in such a way that whenever the bash script is executed , it should firstly check if my local bash script is on par with the github, if not script should end and update itself

Comment: Use `git pull` to update your script

Comment: @Sami Its not about how i update my script. Its about how i automatically git fetch and reset every time the bash script is executed

Comment: Ah sorry I did not understand that. So what you could do, I guess, is create a launcher script that will do the `git reset --hard script` and the launch your script. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @Sami Yes such approach would suffice as long as my local bash script is automatically being updated..although i never got around making any such launcher script.    Just tell me how i can include my git fetch and git reset command in launcher script and then add reference to my main script

Answer (score 1):

Make the script update and re-execute itself if necessary:

```
#!/bin/sh
git fetch
if test `git rev-parse @{upstream}` != `git rev-parse @`; then
        git reset --hard @{upstream}
        exec "$0" "$@"
fi
```